# Useful methods to avoid degenerate calibration? (Heston model in my case)

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, calibration

I have implemented a Levenberg-Marquardt(LM) based method to calibrate the Heston model against market data by minimizing a weighted $L^2$-norm of differences of market vs model prices. Pretty standard stuff.
The calibration works pretty well and fits the market data as good as could be expected.

As a reference, the Heston model is given by the processes:
$$ dS_t = \mu \cdot S_t dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} \cdot S_t dW^S_t$$
$$ 
d\nu_t = \kappa \cdot (\theta - \nu_t)  dt + \xi \sqrt{\nu_t} dW^{\nu}_t
$$
where
$$ dW^S_t \cdot dW^{\nu}_t = \rho dt$$
and $v_t$  has initial value $= \nu_0.$
The Heston parameters are given by the tuple $(\kappa, \rho, \xi, \theta, \nu_0).$

 
The parameters of the model have some natural boundaries. The correlation, $\rho$, for example, should be in the interval $[-1, 1]$ and the rest of the parameters should be non-negative.
My problem is that the LM minimizer sometimes end up hitting the boundary of the allowed parameter space and "wants" to go further in that direction. So the calibration then ends up with say $\rho = -1$ or some other parameter equal or close to zero. 
This might not be a huge problem when it comes to fitting the market data, but it will affect the quality of the stochastic behavior of the calibrated Heston model if used in Monte Carlo simulations for example.
 
To make a simple example, let us say that the vol-vol, $\xi$, is calibrated to some value very close to or equal to zero. Then we practically have a deterministic volatility model, which probably will not be very useful. In this case we would probably have been more satisfied with a slightly worse fit to market data, but with no degenerate values of the model parameters.

My question is to get some advice on methods to prevent degenerate model values in the calibration. 
A read a bit about penalty functions to prevent the minimizer to search too close to the boundary of the parameter space. Could this be a way to go? What forms of penalty functions are appropriate then?
My worry here is that the penalty function might affect the calibration too much even when we are not close to the boundary?

This question is, of course, not specific to the Heston model. This seems to be a reoccurring problem in most model calibrations.

Comment: Hey Jesper - have you tried convert the option prices (both market and model) into implied volatilities and L2 norm those diffs? Another idea is to pull in market prices (where possible) for other related quantities like fair varswap strikes at diff expiries to help anchor the model to more than just European prices. Presume you have multiple expiries of European in there, not just one slice?

Comment: Yes, I have tried comparing volatilites as well. Typically I use inverse vega weights when comparing option prices to somewhat emulate the volatility comparing case. Seems to work well.
Yes, using data for several maturities is more or less necessary in the Heston model to capture the model time dependency, so I never use just one maturity.

Comment: It is not that there is anything really wrong with the minmizing procedure. It is trying to do its job, but it cannot know which model values are degenerate and avoid them, unless I modify the minimizing function to avoid the boundaries somehow.

Comment: You could penalise parameters as they near the boundaries of reasonableness I.e. |rho|<0.99 but do it in a smooth way. I often use sigmoid functions to activate incrementally as I near regions which will cause degeneracy or numerical issues with my chosen method to generate model prices. Ita all a bit science and a bit of art...

Comment: That sounds like a good idea with some sigmoid related penalty terms. We need the function to be differentiable and also not not affect things away from the boundaries too much.
Yes, as you say, this seems to both a science, art and trial and error at the same time :)

Comment: What initial guesses do you use? Do you have the same problems if you use a different optimiser? Perhaps even a global optimisation routine? Have you tried minimising relative pricing errors rather than absolute/squared pricing errors? Finally, choose some Heston parameters, calculate corresponding option prices and try to calibrate the model. Do you recover your original parameter values?

Comment: I have tried a variety of different ways to optimize, except adding penalty terms. Your last suggestion is a very good thing to try. I cannot believe I missed doing that, thanks, will try that. Then I can rule out major problems with the optimizer if I get back my original values.

Comment: Can you perhaps share some implied volatilities (with strike, interest rate, dividend yield, underlying value, maturity, etc.) that you failed to calibrate properly? Then we can try whether can replicate that failure or try out different ways of fixing it?

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan have you had any success? do you mind sharing the code, I am trying to develop the same.